# loop every variable once in bash and not loop it every other variable in second loop?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, scripting

how to for loop every variable once in bash ?

I have tried two for loop but it is looping the given variable with every other second variable in loop !

**Tried**

```
for i in 4k 1m 1m
do
   for j in 1m 2m 4m
   do
   echo $i $j
   done
done
```

**Output**

```
4k 1m
4k 2m
4k 4m
1m 1m
1m 2m
1m 4m
1m 1m
1m 2m
1m 4m
```

**Desired output**

```
4k 1m
1m 1m
1m 2m
```

Comment: I'm baffled. I really don't see the logic behind your "desired output".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your lists are stored elsewhere; otherwise, the solution would be to read from an appropriate here document:

```
while read -r i j; do
  echo "$i" "$j"
done <<EOF
4k 1m
1m 1m
1m 2m
EOF
```

But let's say you have `list1=( 4k 1m 1m)` and `list2=(1m 2m 4m)`. `bash` doesn't provide a particularly clean way to "zip" the two arrays together. The best you can do is assume that both lists have the same indices, and iterate over those:

```
list1=(4k 1m 1m)
list2=(1m 2m 4m)
for k in "${!list1[@]}"; do
  i=${list1[k]}
  j=${list2[k]}
  echo "$i" "$j"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ is=( 4k 1m 1m )
$ js=( 1m 2m 4m )
$ paste <(printf '%s\n' "${is[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${js[@]}")
4k      1m
1m      2m
1m      4m
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: I want it to go in a loop !

Comment: But why? That's almost certainly the wrong way to do whatever it is you're trying to do. See the link I provided in my answer.

Comment: I am going to use this variable as an input to an command. I want the command to use these two variables in a combination

Comment: That;s fine but again, a loop like you're asking for is still almost certainly the wrong approach. As a trivial example add `| xargs -n2 printf '<%s:%s>\n'` to the end of the `paste` line and you'll see `printf` getting called with 2 values at a time and no loop required. If you post a question showing what it is you're really trying to do then we can help you.